# Azure B2C custom policy. How to check email domain with REST API on "Send verification code" button

Tags: email-validation, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using starter custom policy XML files for social and MFA
I have created the REST API and called  from  to verify the email domain (server logic is needed). This works fine but the signup page calls my API when the "Create" button is clicked. But I need to call it when the "Send verification code" button is clicked. Is it possible to do?

[image]

Here is my code.

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
            <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
                <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <CryptographicKeys>
                <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
            </CryptographicKeys>
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            </InputClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
                <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateProfile" />
                <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
            </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>



<ClaimsProvider>
    <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-ValidateProfile">
            <DisplayName>Check loyaltyId Azure Function web hook</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://myapiservice.com/api/EmailDomainVerification</Item>
                <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
                <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
                <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
                <Item Key="DebugMode">true</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_siteid" />
            </InputClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isAllowedEmail" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="errorMessage" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
            </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```